# What is causing deleted function error message?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a main program that uses two templates classes Trans and Travel, and it generates a compilation error `use of deleted function 'MakeColor::MakeColor()`, and also: `note: 'MakeColor::MakeColor()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed`. How can I fix this?

class Travel:

```
#include "Trans.hpp"
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Travel {

    public: 

    typedef Trans<A, B> CarType;
    typedef Trans<C, int> BoatType;

    typedef typename CarType::Newest NewestCar;
    typedef typename BoatType::Newest NewestBoat;
};
```

class Trans:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Trans {

    public: 

    class Newest;
};
```

main program:

```
#include "Travel.hpp"
#include "Trans.hpp"


Travel<MakeColor, MakeMaterial, MakeSize>

struct MakeColor {
  CarType::NewestCar model; // error
};

int main(){
...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm bad at templates, but I feel there's something wrong with this whole construct: `Travel<MakeColor, X, Y> struct MakeColor {...}`. What is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MakeColor` does not have a default constructor because `CarType::NewestCar` does not have a default constructor.

You'll need to explicitly create a constructor that initializes `model`.

```
struct MakeColor {
  MakeColor() : model( /* pass constructor parameters here */ ) {}
  CarType::NewestCar model; // error
};
```